# Print layout is not covered whole layout of the xaml page?

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, universal

I am working on windows universal app. I have issue regarding Print functionality in UWP.In this issue when  i click on print button it prints the invoice page which is dynamic designed but print not covered whole page layout.

I am just putting my xaml code.

```
<Grid Background="White">

        <Grid Name="gridpopup"  Visibility="Visible" Background="White">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="78"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="150"></RowDefinition>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text=" Print Order :"  FontSize="20" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="#FFF05929" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,-10"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="invoice_inc_id" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text="{Binding id"  FontSize="20" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF05929" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,1,0,2">
                <Image Name="logo"  Height="70"  Margin="220,10,220,0"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,35,0,0" Height="36">
                    <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text=" Customer Name:  "  FontSize="18" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black"  Margin="0,6,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="15,7,0,0" Name="invoice_Customername" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text="{Binding customer_name}"  FontSize="18" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,10,-2,0" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                    <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text=" Phone/Email :  "  FontSize="18" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="Black"  Margin="0,-4,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="15,-5,0,0" Name="invoiceCustomeremail" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text="{Binding customer_email}" FontSize="18" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Width="210" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

            <ListView Grid.Row="2" Name="lstinvoice"  IsHitTestVisible="False" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <ListView.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/LoginImages/gradient_bg.png"/>
                </ListView.Background>
                <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,5,0,8" Height="25">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="400"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Name" Foreground="#FF020202" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Raavi" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFE05022"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="25,0,2,3" Height="31"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Quantity" Foreground="#FF040404" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Raavi" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFE05022"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,-5,-9"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Price" Foreground="#FF080808" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Raavi" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFE05022"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,30,-9"></TextBlock>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="400"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text="{Binding name}"  FontSize="18" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="Black"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="400" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text="{Binding ordered_qty}"  FontSize="18" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="Black"  Margin="0,0,28,0" Width="auto"/>
                                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text="{Binding unit_price}" FontSize="18" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Foreground="Black"  Margin="0,0,40,0" Width="auto"/>

                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
<Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="disscount_pnl_detail" Width="450"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text="Sub Total :  "  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="18" TextAlignment="Right" Foreground="Black" Height="22"  />
                <TextBlock  Name="invoice_subtotal"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Text="$0.00" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Right"  Foreground="#FFFF3400" FontSize="20"  />

                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text="Discount :  " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  FontSize="18"  TextAlignment="Right"  Foreground="Black" Height="22" />
                <TextBlock  Text="$0.00" Name="invoice_discount" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Right"  Foreground="#FFFF3400" FontSize="20"  />


                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text="Tax :  " Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="18" TextAlignment="Right" Foreground="Black" Height="22" />
                <TextBlock  Text="$0.00" Name="invoice_tax" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Right"  Foreground="#FFFF3400" FontSize="20" />

                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text="Shipping And Handling :  "  FontSize="18" Foreground="Black"  TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
                <TextBlock  Name="invoice_shippingcharge" Text="$0.00" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFF3400" TextAlignment="Right"  FontSize="20" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"  />

                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Text="Grand Total :"  FontSize="22"  Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Right"  FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock  Name="invoice_grandtotal" Text="$0.00" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFF3400" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Right"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"  />


            </Grid>
    </Grid>




    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, you can set `FontFamily` for those `TextBlock`. Once you add `FontFamily` in those `TextBlock`, they will be printed properly.

We can set `FontFamily` in those `TextBlock` like `<TextBlock Name="invoice_subtotal" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" .../>` one by one. Or as all `TextBlock`s are using "Arial Narrow" font, we can set it in a style that target all `TextBlock`s in this `Grid` like

```
<Grid Name="gridpopup" Background="White" Visibility="Visible">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial Narrow" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you so much seriously. I have been facing this issue from last 10 days.You are so Genius.Actully I have tried a lot but i did not get any solution.But really thank you so much for this solution.